# Python linter warning about variables used after for loop?

Tags: python, pylint

Is there a linter / linter setting that will produce warnings when a variable that was defined inside a for/while loop is used after the end of the loop (at which point it will be whatever it was set to in the last loop iteration)? For example, I would like it to warn about the `print` statement here:

```py
numbers = range(10)
for x in numbers:
    if x % 2 == 0:
        y = x
print(y)
```

Comment: Doesn't it have it by default? https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/undefined-loop-variable.html

Comment: Emm why should we need something like this? Maybe I don't exactly get you. Please show it in a code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like pylint can check for this.

https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/undefined-loop-variable.html

I'd just learn to avoid writing code like this to begin with. Just because you can, doesn't mean you should. Although it can be convenient at times, especially for debugging, I think it can lead to harder code to debug.

Comment: Add more content than just linking, give an example in your post itself; plz.